# Hamburger meu not showing on ios

Tags: html, ios, navigation, hamburger-menu

Let me start with I'm not a programmer so I've been banging my head against a wall for hours. Everything works perfectly on desktop and android mobile. But on ios when I click the hamburger menu it just changes colour as expected but the navigation menu does not appear. I have read this is an issue with ios but I can't find any samples similar to get any sort of fix. Any info is appreciated. Please let me know if I need to post css etc. Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="navbar-header ">
            
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index"><img src="images/logo-white.png" alt="logo"></a>
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle menubtn" data-toggle="collapse" data-    
    target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only" >Toggle navigation</span> 
                TEST
                <div id="nav-icon1">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <nav class="fill">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="about-us" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us         
   <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="about-us">History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="faqs">FAQs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index#contact">Contact</a></li>
            
              
                
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: So this is an HTML question? Why isn’t it tagged?

Comment: it's a pwa app? add more info about the app language and we may be able to help you

Comment: Sorry guys I definitely know know the lingo - I don't know what a pwa app is and sorry Matt this is my first post - I didn't know I needed to tag anything with html